# Can't Log In on Facebook Gameroom(Unity windows)

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-gameroom

I have an app that is working fine with facebook on android and iOS, but when I try to build windows version for facebook gameroom I always get loginResult cancelled. Even when I created a fresh project and imported sdk with example scenes I still get cancelled when I try to log in inside FB gameroom.

Login callback:

```
    6/8/2018 02:26:50 PM
Facebook.Unity.LoginResult
LoginResult:
    Error: null
    RawResult: {"cancelled":true,"callback_id":"2"}
    Cancelled: True
LoginResult:
    AccessToken: null

6/8/2018 02:26:42 PM
OnInitCompleteCalled IsLoggedIn='False' IsInitialized='True'
```

Any suggestion? Should I use different method to Log users inside FB gameroom?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?